# can we have some platforms use a shared dart implementation in a flutter plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to support all platforms in my flutter plugin. But only ios/macos/android have their platform implementations. Here is what it looks like in `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
  plugin:
    platforms:
      android:
        pluginClass: MyPlugin
      ios:
        pluginClass: MyPlugin
      linux:
        pluginClass: MyPlugin
      macos:
        pluginClass: MyPlugin
      windows:
        pluginClass: MyPlugin
```

I'd like to delegate windows/linux implementations to a shared dart implementation, something like:

```yaml
  plugin:
    platforms:
      android:
        pluginClass: MyPlugin
      ios:
        pluginClass: MyPlugin
      linux:
        pluginClass: ../common/dartImplementation
      macos:
        pluginClass: MyPlugin
      windows:
        pluginClass: ../common/dartImplementation
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

For Dart only platform implementations, you can take a look at the official federated plugin documentation, which can be found here: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#dart-only-platform-implementations.

> In some cases, some platforms *can be implemented entirely in Dart* (for example, using FFI). For a Dart-only platform implementation on a platform other than web, replace the `pluginClass` in pubspec.yaml with a `dartPluginClass`. Here is the `hello_windows` example above modified for a Dart-only implementation:

```yaml
flutter:
  plugin:
    implements: hello
    platforms:
      windows:
        dartPluginClass: HelloPluginWindows
```